# Lift: How to bind a Hyperlink to a serverside method

Tags: lift

I am new to Lift, I want to use hyperlink instead of submit button. I am able to bind my submit button with a server-side method use CSS Selector. for example:

```
  def render = {
    // define some variables to put our values into
// process the form
def process() {
      do something....
  }
}

  "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
```

}

I want to use hyperlink to submit my form instead of submit button. How can I bind hyperlink with process()(server-side) method.

Thanks,
Puneet

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you would probably want to use SHtml.ajaxCall and supply the form information as the JsonContext (i.e. not bound with CSS selectors):

```
def ajaxCall (jsCalcValue: JsExp, jsContext: JsContext, func: (String) ⇒ JsCmd) : (String, JsExp)
```

Alternativly you could use SHtml.a:

```
def a (func: () ⇒ JsObj, jsonContext: JsonContext, body: NodeSeq, attrs: ElemAttr*) : Elem
```

Failing that you should look at the available methods in SHtml (jsonForm would be another one to look at) and see which one best fits your use case. I would encourage you to pick up a copy of Lift in Action which discusses how the function binding works, as I think you have miss-understood it in relation to the request/response cycle.